# Is the LinkedIn REST API accessible client side?

Tags: rest, cors, client, linkedin-api

I'm building a React app and Express API with a "Sign in with LinkedIn" feature. I've got my OAuth sorted, so I have an access token now but I keep getting a CORS issue when I try using it to *fetch* data. Can I make REST API requests directly from my React app (client side)? Or do I need to proxy every request through my own Express server / API?

```
useEffect(() => {

    // get linkedin data
    fetch(`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me`, {
      method: 'get',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
      },
    }).then(response => response.json()).then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });

  }, []);
```

> Access to fetch at 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: The LinkedIn API no longer supports requests from frontend JavaScript code running a browser. See the *The JavaScript SDK is not currently supported* note at https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk and see the blog entry at https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates

Comment: @sideshowbarker Thanks for confirming that. I just wish they made that clear. Ending support for an SDK and announcing OAuth 2.0 doesn't mean their REST API isn't supported client side.